# How to update in Laravel Eloquent (HasMany Relationship)

Tags: php, laravel

i had two modules which are Product and Items Modules Here the relationship between these two module are: Product hasMany items and Items belongsTo product

The table for Product Module are: id, product_name The table for Items Module are: id, products_id, item_name, quantity, price

This is my code for UPDATE

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->product_name = $request->product_name;
    $product->update();
    // Remove all items and add new
    $product->items()->delete();
    // Save each items
    if($request->get('item_name')){
        foreach($request->get('item_name') as $key => $item_name)
        {   
            $items = new Items();
            $items->products_id = $product->id;
            $items->item_name = $item_name;
            $items->quantity = $request->quantity[$key];
            $items->price = $request->price[$key];
            $items->save();
        };
    };
}
```

The structure for this UPDATE code is whenever there is an update, each items will be deleted and update information will be added as new row.

What i want is the items SHOULD NOT be deleted and add as new. This is because i wants to MAINTAIN THE ITEMS ID. What should i modified to my current code?

Comment: maybe just remove this $product->items()->delete(); assumed you have set hasMany relations, to retrieve product items just use Product::find(1)->items;

Comment: like this? `Product::find($id)->items` @AlzafanChristian its not working..

Comment: you should send item ids as an array in your request collection from view. And then update the specific item information by item id inside the for loop.

Comment: you didnt get what i mean, if just updating Product, no need to delete relations or making a new Item. then if u want to add new Item, add the foreign key to parent primary key. thats the clue

Comment: @MOHAMMADABUKAWSAR suggest is working thanks so much. thanks to you too Alzafan Christian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your purpose is to make it more dynamic to **add**, **delete** and **update** the items we have to handle this with another way!
Unfortunately Laravel does not provide some method like `sync()` to handle **many-to-one** relationships, just with **many-to-many**. So you have to insert some additional logic into your code. We will use the `id` key to handle this logic.
 So, for this works, all the product items came from request must have the key `id`. The new items (those that do not yet exist in the database) must have the `id` key empty.

For example:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "quantity": 2,
    "price": 10,
    "product_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Item 2",
    "quantity": 3,
    "price": 22,
    "product_id": 1,
  },
  {
    "id": "",
    "name": "Item 3",
    "quantity": 9,
    "price": 33,
    "product_id": 1,
  }
]
```

Note the just the first item will be updated, the second and third will be added because the `id` key is empty, and the items that dont came into array but exists on the database will be deleted.

So, lets go!

1 - Create 3 auxiliary variables to **items with id**, **items without id** and **items id**. Note that we use `collect()` method to help us to handle the arrays:

```
$items_without_id = collect($items)->where('id', '');
$items_with_id = (clone collect($items))->where('id', '!=', '');
$items_ids = $items_with_id->pluck('id');
```

2 - Update the items with id:

```
foreach ($items_with_id as $item) {
   $obj = App\ProductItem::find($item['id']);
   $obj->name = $item['name'];
   $obj->price = $item['price'];
   $obj->quantity = $item['quantity'];
   $obj->save();
}
```

3 - Remove items that don't came into the array, we supposed that these items have to be deleted:

```
$product->items()->whereNotIn('id', $items_ids)->delete();
```

4 - Finally insert items that came without id. We supposed that these items  has to be added:

```
$items_without_id->each(function ($item) use ($product) {
   $obj = new App\ProductItem();
   $obj->name = $item['name'];
   $obj->price = $item['price'];
   $obj->quantity = $item['quantity'];
   $obj->product_id = $product->id;
   $obj->save();
});
```

Full code:

```
$product = App\Product::findOrFail($id);
$items = $request->items;

$items_without_id = collect($items)->where('id', '');
$items_with_id = (clone collect($items))->where('id', '!=', '');
$items_ids = $items_with_id->pluck('id');

foreach ($items_with_id as $item) {
   $obj = App\ProductItem::find($item['id']);
   $obj->name = $item['name'];
   $obj->price = $item['price'];
   $obj->quantity = $item['quantity'];
   $obj->save();
}

$product->items()->whereNotIn('id', $items_ids)->delete();

$items_without_id->each(function ($item) use ($product) {
   $obj = new App\ProductItem();
   $obj->name = $item['name'];
   $obj->price = $item['price'];
   $obj->quantity = $item['quantity'];
   $obj->product_id = $product->id;
   $obj->save();
});
```

Testing with postman:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzfry.png)

Hope this helps. Sorry for my bad english.